# MAX(column) when column has duplicates

Tags: sql, aggregate-functions, greatest-n-per-group

Say I have the table t1:

```
c1 | c2 | c3| c4
 1    1    1   A
 1    1    2   B
 1    1    3   C
 1    1    4   D
 1    1    4   E
 1    1    4   F
 2    2    1   A
 2    2    2   A
 2    2    3   A
```

I want to select the row for each c1, c2 pair that has the maximum c3. The question is, which row would be selected if I did a max(c3) for each c1,c2 then self joined back to the original table? Would it just select one of the three rows where c3=4 at random?

Comment: If you `JOINED` back to the original table on that value, it would select all of them.

Comment: Whats is your database?

Comment: No, it would select all of them.

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't need a join:

```
 select c1,c2,c3,maxc3 from (
    SELECT c1,c2, c3,MAX(c3) OVER () as maxc3
    FROM @temp
    GROUP BY c1,c2,c3
    ) a
    where c3 = maxc3
```

Answer (score 0):

All depends from the join clause - if you get the `MAX(c3)` and the `JOIN` BACK the result:

- If you join by columns `c1` and `c2` you will have all 3 rows.
- If you add distinct top previous combination you will have only 1 row.
- If you join by columns `c1`,`c2` and `c3` - you will have 1 row.

Answer (score 0):

> *which row would be selected if I did a max(c3) for each c1,c2 then*
>   *self joined back to the original table?*

=> The answer to this is that all rows that match back to your `max(c3)` value will be selected.

> *Would it just select one of the three rows where c3=4 at random?*

=> No, same as above. Any matching `max(c3)` with the column `c3` in your self join table will be returned (**for e.g.** your `c1` and `c2` value of 1 will return 3 rows since it has max value of 4 in three rows). To limit the self join on `c3`, you may need to join back on `c1` and `c2` columns as well.

```
select t1.*
from table1 t1
join 
(
select 
      c1,
      c2,
      max(c3) as c3
 from table1
 group by c1,c2
 ) t on  t.c1 = t1.c1
     and t.c2 = t1.c2
     and t.c3 = t1.c3
 order by t.c1,t.c2
```

[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d80e79/9/0)